# error with the Ajax to show 3 user per page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am trying to show a 3 user per page using Pagination using jquery,mySql and PHP so i follow some tutorial in this page :

http://php-dev-zone.blogspot.com/2013/09/simple-pagination-using-jquerymysql-and.html

i got 2 errors

the first error is that my platform do not support Mysql_query so i change it to Mysqli_query so i thing it is fixed

the second error is the page is displaying the page number only without the users info !?

can any one help me please

this is an image to show how is the page :

http://store1.up-00.com/2014-02/1391845579081.jpg

and those are my files after changing them to Mysqli_query

Config.php

```
    <?php

$db_username = '****';
$db_password = '*****';
$db_name = '*****';
$db_host = '********';
$item_per_page = 3;


$connecDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('could not connect to database');
?>
```

data.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$per_page = 3; 
if($_GET)
{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}

//getting table contents
$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
$sql = "select * from users order by id limit $start,$per_page";
$rsd = mysqli_query($sql);
?>



<table id="tb1">
        <th><b>Id</b></th>
        <th><b>FirstName</b></th>
        <th><b>Email</b></th>
        <th><b>LastName</b></th>
        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd))
        {
            $id    = $row['id'];
            $fname = $row['first_name'];
            $mname    = $row['email'];
            $lname    = $row['last_name'];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        } //End while
        ?>
</table>

<style>
#tbl
{
width:800px;
border:1px solid #000000;
margin-top:50px;
}

#tbl tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #000000
}

#tbl td{
border:1px solid #000000
}

#tbl th
{
  background: #00000;
border:1px solid #000000
}
</style>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$per_page = 3; 

//getting number of rows and calculating no of pages

$sql = "select count(*) from users";
$result = mysqli_query($connecDB,$sql);
$count = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$pages = ceil($count[0]/$per_page);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PHPDevZone : Pagination Using Mysql and jQuery </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/2141420575/pagination.js"></script>   
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family:Verdana; font-size:15px }
a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;

}

a:hover
{

color:#DF3D82;
text-decoration:underline;

}
#loading { 
width: 100%; 
position: absolute;
}

#pagination
{
text-align:center;
margin-left:120px;

}
li{ 
list-style: none; 
float: left; 
margin-right: 16px; 
padding:5px; 
color:#0063DC; 
}
li:hover
{ 
color:#FF0084; 
cursor: pointer; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
   <div style="margin-top:300px;"><b><a href="http://php-dev-zone.blogspot.com" > PHPDevZone </a></b>: Pagination Demo</div>
 <div id="content" ></div>
    <table width="800px">
    <tr><Td>
            <ul id="pagination">
                <?php
                //Show page links
                for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
                {
                    echo '<li id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
                }
                ?>
           </ul>    
        </Td>
    </tr></table>
<div id="loading" ></div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

pagination.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    //Loading Image Display
    function Display_Load()
    {
        $("#loading").fadeIn(100);
        $("#loading").html("<img src='loading.gif' />");
    }
    //Hide Loading Image
    function Hide_Load()
    {
        $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
    };


   //Default Starting Page Results

    $("#pagination li:first").css({'color' : '#FF0084','border' : 'none'});
    $("#content").load("data.php?page=1", Hide_Load());

    //Pagination Click
    $("#pagination li").click(function(){
        Display_Load();

        //CSS Styles
        $("#pagination li")
        .css({'border' : 'solid #dddddd 1px'})
        .css({'color' : '#0063DC'});

        $(this)
        .css({'color' : '#FF0084'})
        .css({'border' : 'none'});

        //Loading Data
        var pageNum = this.id;
        $("#content").load("data.php?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your mysqli_query in Data.php page.
mysqli_query first need a database link and then query, so your code have to be like this to get it works:

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$per_page = 3;
if ($_GET) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

//getting table contents
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$sql = "select * from users order by id limit $start,$per_page";
$rsd = mysqli_query($connecDB,$sql);
?>



<table id="tb1">
        <th><b>Id</b></th>
        <th><b>FirstName</b></th>
        <th><b>Email</b></th>
        <th><b>LastName</b></th>
        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd))
        {
            $id    = $row['id'];
            $fname = $row['first_name'];
            $mname    = $row['email'];
            $lname    = $row['last_name'];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } //End while ?>
</table>

<style>
    #tbl {
        width: 800px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #tbl tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #000000
    }

    #tbl td {
        border: 1px solid #000000
    }

    #tbl th {
        background: #00000;
        border: 1px solid #000000
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond i change the data.php but the problem still there the index page does not show any users

Comment: Did you changed the query ? " $sql = "select * from users order by id limit $start,$per_page"; " because i changed mybb_users to users. And are you sure there is data in table ?

Comment: yes i changed the query and i am sure about the data in table more than 5 record  thank you for respond

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything wrong with your code instead of some unimportant undefined variable errors. If you want i can help you on ymsgr: tje3d(AT)y!

Comment: i really try every thing i do not know why it is not work maybe there is a connection problem between data.php and index.php if you can help me with any thing please  thank you